# Rearrange c++ const and reference specifiers

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-c++

I'm trying to convert

```
const std::string &s
```

to

```
std::string const & s
```

and can't seem to get it quite right. This is the regex I'm using:

```
%s/const \(.\{-}\) &/\1 const &
```

and the result I'm getting:

```
std::string const const std::string &s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the `&` with a backslash.

```
%s/const \(.\{-}\) &/\1 const \&
```

The `&` in the replace part inserts the entire matched pattern.

See `:help s/\&`.